# Facebook fan box bugged

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a custom fanbox on a website, it was working fine but when i see today it was bugged, does facebook changed the api or something?

I didnt built it myself, i just get it working from another site, it calls a css that i have on my FTP.. You can check the bug here www.shoppingdifusora.com.br on the bottom of the page.

I made the faces all together without margin and smaller (without names too) and there was neither border nor Find us..
can somebody help me?

here the html:

```
<div id="facebook">
                        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/ShoppingDifusora" title="Ir para o facebook" rel="external"></a>
                        <fb:fan profile_id="408396085874237" connections="21" width="300" height="205" show_faces="true" stream="false" header="false" css="http://www.shoppingdifusora.com.br/site/assets/stylesheet/facebook.css?25"></fb:fan>
                    </div>
```

js:

```
<script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                FB.init({
                appId: '145103648914101',
                cookie: true,
                xfbml: true,
                oauth: true
            });

            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
                window.location.reload();
            });

            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
                window.location.reload();
            });
        };
    </script>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=168546436606787";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The FB fanbox is an old way of adding the plugin that allowed for more customization by adding your own css sheet.

It looks like Facebook has updated their code so that the fanbox is now showing their standard like box. There's a lot less flexibility on the styling for it. I suggest you look at the FB documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

You'll need to replace your fanbox code with updated likebox code in order to correct this.

Comment: i tried to put the new js and fbml code but it didnt seem to load the css, do you know how to load a external css?

Comment: It looks like it is no more possibile to use custom css with the old plugin, that's a pity, no more ways to customize look? :(

Comment: sorry, looks like they've stopped allowing you to customize with the css. We've had to rework spaces to accomodate their layout. This is the downside to using code controlled by the supplier - they can change their minds on how it's used.